# How I can change the default spring-security 2.0 login page in grails app?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, grails-2.5

I need configurate my web application to login with spring-security using username store in my DBs' app(im using PostgreSQL) from my auth.gsp page. How i performance this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check out http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core ?

Comment: Sorry if my question was ambiguous, I had already install spring-security-core-2.0 however, i can't log in in the app with the username that I have in my database.

Comment: Please give more details: show your code or stacktrace or any other helpfull info.

Comment: @AlejandroMariñoMolerio is the password encrypted in the database?  if not, then the password check for login will fail.

Comment: @NickHammond, Yes, the password is encrypted  in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really is very simple, but I didnt know. I create another auth.gsp with my specific css and js, and in field text I named same as in default auth.gsp generate by spring security plugin. My auth.gsp is located in grails-app/view